# How to add a resource type via application.ini

Tags: zend-framework

How can I add this resource type in application.ini. (In Bootstrap.php is working but I'd prefer in application.ini if that is possible...)

```
protected function _initResourceLoader()
{
    $this->_resourceLoader->addResourceType( 'service', 'services/', 'Service' );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own application resource:

```
class My_Resource_Resourceloader extends Zend_Application_Resource_ResourceAbstract
{
    public function init()
    {
        $options = $this->getOptions();

        /* @var $resourceLoader Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource */
        $resourceLoader = $this->getBootstrap()->getResourceLoader();
        foreach ($options as $method => $params) {
            if (method_exists($resourceLoader, $method)) {
                call_user_func_array(array($resourceLoader, $method), $params);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Specify resource path in application.ini :

```
pluginpaths.My_Resource = "My/Resource"
```

Configure single resource:

```
resources.resourceloader.addResourceType.1 = "service"
resources.resourceloader.addResourceType.2 = "services/"
resources.resourceloader.addResourceType.3 = "Service"
```

Configure multiple resources:

```
resources.resourceloader.addResourceTypes.1.acl.path = "acls/"
resources.resourceloader.addResourceTypes.1.acl.namespace = "Acl"
resources.resourceloader.addResourceTypes.1.service.path = "services/"
resources.resourceloader.addResourceTypes.1.service.namespace = "Service"
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know this way but I think I prefer the original because is shorter and simpler